# Disabling tooltip on menu items

Tags: menus

For some reason, my menu items are showing tooltips on hover-over- In other words, the menu links have "title" attributes being added to them.  Looking at my other, older WordPress sites, this is not the case.  I can't remember having this issue before- Why would this be happening?

Thanks-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s the code to remove it from wp_page_menu(), wp_nav_menu() and wp_list_categories() function:

```
function my_menu_notitle( $menu ){
  return $menu = preg_replace('/ title=\"(.*?)\"/', '', $menu );

}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', 'my_menu_notitle' );
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu', 'my_menu_notitle' );
add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'my_menu_notitle' );
```

[Source](http://www.dynamicwp.net/articles-and-tutorials/remove-title-attribute-from-wordpress-menu-link/)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding a explicitly creating a menu vs relying on the default.  Don't know why this would help (Figured it was an argument in wp_nav_menu_args but I couldn't find any dealing with this.)